# How to run a Ruby application in Cloud9 IDE that uses Ruby 2D gem?

Tags: ruby, ide, cloud9

I am using Cloud9 IDE and have Ruby gems simple2d and ruby2d installed. I am trying to run this code:

```
require 'ruby2d'
set width: 300, height: 200
s = Square.new
s.color = 'red'
show
```

When I run my code, the small terminal at the bottom of the screen says something like "Your code is running at...link_goes_here". Clicking the link takes you to a page very similar to: [Ruby on Rails: Welcome Aboard](http://web.mit.edu/zelda/BACKUPS/).

I am very new to Ruby, but understand that this page indicates that "additional steps" may need to be taken in order to see your application run (i.e. setting up models, controller, and routes). However, after a little bit of Googling, it seems that people only do these "additional steps" when doing "HTML" related things (please excuse my lack of proper terminology). For example, [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) walks the reader through changing the [Ruby on Rails: Welcome Aboard](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) page to say "Hello, Rails" (and then other things after that).

Can someone please explain/show me what to do in order to run my code?

Thanks!

**EDIT: 2018-03-27**

It appears that I have a Gemfile: [Cloud9 IDE Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elKSC.png)

When I ran `bundle install` I got the following output:

`Using rake 12.0.0
Using i18n 0.8.6
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using activesupport 4.2.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.2.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.0
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using actionview 4.2.5
Using rack 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.5
Using globalid 0.4.0
Using activejob 4.2.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using mime-types 3.1
Using mail 2.6.6
Using actionmailer 4.2.5
Using activemodel 4.2.5
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.5
Using debug_inspector 0.0.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using byebug 9.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 4.2.5
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using rails 4.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.1
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using sdoc 0.4.2
Using spring 2.0.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using web-console 2.3.0
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Use bundle info [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

I still run into the same issue when trying to run my code.

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile`? Did you `bundle install`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears that I have a Gemfile, and I tried running bundle install with no luck-see the edit above.